# android app running multiple threads on a canvas crashes after showing ad

Tags: android, multithreading, admob, android-canvas

my android app shows a canvas with multiple sprites on it, sprites have their own threads, a banner ad shows on the bottom, when ad is clicked it shows full ad, clicking return button to go back to the app crashes the app, can't find log cat.

Here's the gameView class code which creates gameLoopthread

```
public GameView(Context context) {
         super(context);
         tmpcontext = context;
         gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
         bmpback = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e_castle_1);


         getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                       boolean retry = true;
                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                       while (retry) {
                              try {
                                    gameLoopThread.join();
                                    retry = false;
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                       }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                       createSprites();
                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                       if(gameviewcreated == false) gameLoopThread.start();  

                       if(gameviewcreated == true)
                        try {
                            gameLoopThread.join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                       gameviewcreated = true;

                }
```

origionally i had only gameLoopThread.start() in surfaceCreated method so it was trying to start the thread again after displaying the ad when user clicked it, thus blowing up, now i have added check to see gameviewcreated already created. Its not crashing but not bringing original thread so its not showing canvas or sprites, thought join should do that.

Comment: There has to be some logcat. You need to post what you have.

Comment: added code, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be really confused about how Threads should be used in Java.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

Join will block until the Thread dies.

It's very hard to comment on your code because it's not obvious when or how GameView is constructed, nor what you have down with GameLoopThread. I suspect you want to be controlling the Thread lifecycle from GameView not from your SurfaceHolder callback. I also recommend that you use a plain Thread object and pass a Runnable to it that does your logic. The separation of the two will do wonders for your coding style.

Comment: agree with u, new to using thread. I had tried the code without join and it didn't work. My screen is showing sprites on the canvas and user click the banner ad, when he click back, program should resume automatically and should be handled by the system, i shouldn't have to  do anything.